# Linq query with grouping to fetch youngest date

Tags: c#, linq

My case, see below image:
[image]

I designed a query and added a grouping but the grouping does not reduce the records to the youngest ContractEndDate. It appears to have no effect on the result.

```
public IQueryable<SoonObsoleteContractsViewModel> Get()
    {

var countries = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Country>();
var companies = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Company>();
var contracts = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Contract>();

var query = from country in countries
            join company in companies on country.Id equals company.CountryId
            join contract in contracts on company.Id equals contract.CompanyId

            select new SoonObsoleteContractsViewModel
            {
                CountryName = contry.Name,
                CompanyName = company.Name,
                CompanyId = company.CompanyId
                ContractBeginDate = contract.Begin,
                ContractEndDate = contract.End,
                ContractId = contract.Id
            };

            query.GroupBy(c => c.CompanyId, (key, e) => e.OrderBy(f => f.ContractEndDate).First());
        return query;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "grouped by company and country"? In your example, you choose the youngest contract from each country, irrespective of the company.

Comment: @yinnonsanders: sorry, I was not clear. Since a country can have n different companies there can be n records for each country with the youngest contract for each company within the country group. I will correct my tables.

Comment: *"It appears to have no effect on the result."* How about `var result = query.GroupBy(....` (forgot that LINQ methods return results?)

Comment: @Manu Thanks for the clarification. I think there should still be an extra entry for Germany in the result but the intent is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by country and company then get the record in the group with most recent contract end date.

```
var result = query
             .GroupBy(_ => new { _.CountryName, _.CompanyId})
             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContractEndDate).First())
             .ToList();
```

Or put another way

```
var query = from contry in countries
            join company in companies on country.Id equals company.CountryId
            join contract in contracts on company.Id equals contract.CompanyId
            let viewModel = new SoonObsoleteContractsViewModel
            {
                CountryName = contry.Name,
                CompanyName = company.Name,
                CompanyId = company.CompanyId
                ContractBeginDate = contract.Begin,
                ContractEndDate = contract.End,
                ContractId = contract.Id
            }
            group viewModel by new { viewModel.CountryName, viewModel.CompanyId } into g
            select g.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContractEndDate).First();
```

Comment: It looks like when I do the grouping after the  } of the select new statement for the ViewModel, it results in an empty list. What If I tried to place the grouping before the ViewModel select -> but what would be the syntax there?

Comment: now error is gone, but -> when query is passed to the view, I get empty list. Without grouping all records are listed as expected

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to NKosi I finally solved it:

```
var query = from contry in countries
        join company in companies on country.Id equals company.CountryId
        join contract in contracts on company.Id equals contract.CompanyId
        let viewModel = new SoonObsoleteContractsViewModel
        {
            CountryName = contry.Name,
            CompanyName = company.Name,
            CompanyId = company.CompanyId
            ContractBeginDate = contract.Begin,
            ContractEndDate = contract.End,
            ContractId = contract.Id
        }
        group viewModel by new { viewModel.CountryName, viewModel.CompanyId } into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContractEndDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

All I had to do was change **First()** to **FirstOrDefault**! Otherwise the query produces an empty list.